# Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library

Tags: windows, visual-c++, windows-xp-sp3

In my external usb harddisk when I click on only the folder names "MISC" I get the error

```
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library

Program: C:\Windows\Explorer.EXE

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Other folders open perfectly without the error.I tried changing the folder name but it did not help.I can use windows explorer to open/expand the folder and sub folder on the left.If I open the root of the folder MISC I get the error.Tried sfc /scannow,avg virus scan of the drive,spybot s&d scan of the system.All clean.No new program was Installed recently.Please guide what to do!

Comment: Not really a programming question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.

This occurs when some code linked to the MS C runtime [calls the C `abort` function](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/12/08/10245330.aspx). Since Explorer doesn't rely on the MS C runtime the most logical conclusion is that you have a misbehaving shell extension. Shell extensions are loaded into the Explorer process and can quite easily wreak havoc like this. I would try this disk on a different machine to test out that theory. Or find a tool that disables shell extensions.

Comment: The files in the folder are video clips.If I run "regsvr32 /u shmedia.dll", I do not get the error but I cannot even see the thumbnail view of the files.I have similar files in other folders also which do not create this error.

Comment: shmedia.dll is a Windows DLL but it's probably relying on other extensions to draw the thumbs. To be honest I'm pretty sure my answer is correct at the high level, but you need some more detailed help. I can't give you that (don't know enough). The question has been closed as off topic so no new answers will appear. This question would be much better off on superuser.com where I'm sure you would get good help. I asked a moderator to migrate the question there but that request was turned down. I suggest you ask the question again at http://superuser.com